# Slow alt-tab (static application switcher) on Ubuntu 18.04.1 and XPS13 1397

Tags: 16.04, graphics, 18.04, intel-graphics

I am on an XPS 13 1397 and have updated Ubuntu from `16.04` to `18.04.1`. What is different, that the `static application switcher` appears only after about 1 sec after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. I have already downloaded `CompizConfig Settings Manager` and configured the `static application switcher` as follows:

```
Behaviour --> Speed --> 50,000
Behaviour --> Timestep --> 10,000
Behaviour --> Popup Window Delay --> 0,000
```

But nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution for the slow `application switcher` (at least for me `XPS 13 9370` - `Ubuntu 18.04.1`):

Install the following extension:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1317/alt-tab-switcher-popup-delay-removal/